Understanding Python ID function, which gives 'unique identifier'

When you declare a value in python, and access its unique identifier both will give same results,
E.g.:

x="ADCAADAFAVVA"
print(id(x)) 
print(id("ADCAADAFAVVA")) 
    
O/P:
123456789
123456789

But when you apply the unique identfier on a value which is not assigned to any object/ variable, how is it giving the ID ?
E.g.:
print(id("ADadasdaaqdas"))
    
O/P:
98231527347


"ADadasdaaqdas" is an object. It will cease to exist right after that line, but it is an object just like "ADCAADAFAVVA" and id is obtained in the same way.

In your second example, the string object is still created and therefore it has an id. You didn't bind it to an identifier, so there is no reference to it, but it still exists (at least in the line where it is used).
Not having a reference to the string just means you can't access it later, you'd have to recreate it. It also means its reference count is zero, so it will be garbage collected some time after the call to id finished.

id is property of an object, not a variable. Whether you assign object to variable or not, it will have an id (in CPython, it is the address of the object in memory.)
The reason for what you observed is string interning (which is an implementation detail, not feature of the language).
Before actually running the code, CPython scans it, recognises repeated strings with the same value and inserts the same object in each place this string is used, regardless of if we assign it to some variable or not. That's why you are seeing same id for both x and "ADCAADAFAVVA". On the other hand, if you later in the code created exact same string, it will have different id.
x="ADCAADAFAVVA"
y_1 = "ADCAAD"
y_2 = "AFAVVA"
y = y_1 + y_2
print(f"{id(x) = }")  # id(x) = 2543639467056
print(f"{id(y) = }")  # id(y) = 2543636071408
print(f"{y == x = }") # y == x = True

So, the fact that x and "ADCAADAFAVVA" have same ids should really be thought of as an exception, not the rule.
